# Need underline to go across the page on tabs and bullet lists not working

Tags: html, css

On my tabs navigation, I have an orange line that is placed below the tabs. I'd like that line to go all the way across the page, but it looks like it doesn't under some of the tabs (check the orange tab). I think it based on the amount of text that is listed in the tab. How do I get the line to go across the entire page no matter how little content there is?

Also, how do I get my "Apples" list to work correctly and show bullets? Currently the types of apples Gala Honeycrisp Pink Lady are all on one line, but I'd like them to be put in a bullet list.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/vm4d3a1q/49/

Here's my html:

```
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li>
        <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-1">Apples</label>
        <div class="nav-tab-content">
            <p><strong>Apples</strong><br />
                The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Gala</li>
                <li>
                    Honeycrisp</li>
                <li>
                    Pink Lady</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab-2" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-2">Orange</label>
        <div class="nav-tab-content">
            <p><strong>Oranges</strong><br />
                Sweet oranges were mentioned in Chinese literature in 314 BC.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Florida</li>
                <li>
                    California</li>
                <li>
                    Washington</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab-3" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-3">Pears</label>
        <div class="nav-tab-content">
            <p><strong>Pears</strong><br />
                The pear is any of several tree and shrub species of genus Pyrus.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Anjou</li>
                <li>
                    Bosc</li>
                <li>
                    Bartlett</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="tab-4" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-4">Banana</label>
        <div class="nav-tab-content">
            <p><strong>Banana</strong><br />
                The banana is an edible fruit, botanically a berry, produced by several kinds of large herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa. In some countries, bananas used for cooking may be called plantains.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Burro</li>
                <li>
                    Plantain</li>
                <li>
                    Red</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    .nav-tabs{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs:after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
}

.nav-tabs li{
display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs li > input{
    display: none;
}

.nav-tabs li > label{
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs li:last-child > label{
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #f66511;
}

/* Functional */

.nav-tabs li > input:checked + label{
    background-color: #2251a4;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs li > input:checked ~ .nav-tab-content{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: you can simply add `.nav-tabs li > div ul li { display: list-item; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick answer

add this rule

```
.nav-tabs li > div ul li { display: list-item; }
```

---

## Understanding the why

you have a rule saying that all `<li>` elements should be displayed as `inline-block`

```
.nav-tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

that will find and match **all** `<li>` even the nested ones... what you need to do if tell the browser that for the nested ones, you would like a different rule... and either you tell *all*  to have the different rule and only the first nested elements have the opposite, or vice versa

the later, a simple nested rule would suffice, the first you should write something like:

```
/* tell that all <li> should be as a list (to have bullets) */
.nav-tabs li { 
    display: list-item;
}

/* tell that only the first nested after .nav-tabs should be inline (the menu) */
.nav-tabs > li { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to `.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content`:

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm4d3a1q/55/)

```
.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #f66511;
}
```

And for the bullets:

```
.nav-tab-content li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the width of your `.nav-tab-content` div 100% like this:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #f66511;
    width:100%;  //this was missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% width to `.nav-tab-content`, for the list inside the tab content add an extra class to the `ul`'s and set the `display`  of the `li`'s back to `list-item`.

```css
.nav-tabs{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs:after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
}

.nav-tabs li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs li > input{
  display: none;
}

.nav-tabs li > label{
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs li:last-child > label{
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #f66511;
}

/* Functional */

.nav-tabs li > input:checked + label{
  background-color: #2251a4;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs li > input:checked ~ .nav-tab-content{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-content-list {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.tab-content-list li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li>
    <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-1">Apples</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p><strong>Apples</strong><br />
        The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>
      <ul class="tab-content-list">
        <li>
          Gala</li>
        <li>
          Honeycrisp</li>
        <li>
          Pink Lady</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-2" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-2">Orange</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p><strong>Oranges</strong><br />
        Sweet oranges were mentioned in Chinese literature in 314 BC.</p>
      <ul class="tab-content-list">
        <li>
          Florida</li>
        <li>
          California</li>
        <li>
          Washington</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-3" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-3">Pears</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p><strong>Pears</strong><br />
        The pear is any of several tree and shrub species of genus Pyrus.</p>
      <ul class="tab-content-list">
        <li>
          Anjou</li>
        <li>
          Bosc</li>
        <li>
          Bartlett</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-4" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-4">Banana</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p><strong>Banana</strong><br />
        The banana is an edible fruit, botanically a berry, produced by several kinds of large herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa. In some countries, bananas used for cooking may be called plantains.</p>
      <ul class="tab-content-list">
        <li>
          Burro</li>
        <li>
          Plantain</li>
        <li>
          Red</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>    
</ul>
```